# Rendezvous in inter process communication?

Tags: process, operating-system, ipc, message-passing

I have two processes communicating through a send() and a receive(). 
If both are blocking, I know this is what is known as **extended rendezvous**, if the sender is non-blocking then it's called **limited rendezvous**.

But what happens when both send() and receive() are non-blocking? Is this another kind of rendezvous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense if both are non-blocking. The way rendezvous might happen in that case, is when both make the calls at exactly the same time.